# String not turning blue and only reading up to space

Tags: c++, string

Here's my actual code, it's skipping the getline(cin,phrase) completely..
maybe there's something else wrong with it, but I can't really find anything wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream outFile;
string file_name;
string phrase;
int number;

cout << "What file would you like to write into? ";
cin >> file_name;

outFile.open(file_name);
if(!outFile)
{
    cout << "Error, could not find file. Press enter to self destruct. " << endl;
    return -1;
}

cout << "What would you like to write? ";
getline (cin, phrase);
cout << "How many times? ";
cin >> number;

while(number != 0)
{
    outFile << phrase;
    number = number - 1;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Try `getline(cin, cookie)`

Comment: You need a [`MCVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you posted doesn't compile. Although I (probably shouldn't) have edited it. Make sure the code you post represents your problem and reproduces the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

cin would read as far as whitespace is not there in your input string. To get around that you can use

```
getline( cin, cookie ).
OR
char input[100];
cin.getline(input,100);
```

EDITED AS TO CLARIFY:-

Show me the output for this :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   string cookie;
   getline ( cin, cookie );
   cout << cookie;
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: the getline(cin,cookie) compiled, but it just skipped it when running the program..

Comment: I tried both and they compiled, but it just skipped them when running the program..

Comment: @JuanMoreno Please respond

Comment: when I put in that code it worked and actually took the entire phrase including spaces and saved it in cookie. 
But when I try to use it on my code it just skips the getline(cin,cookie) completeley,

Comment: @JuanMoreno Then paste the code where you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

The **>>** operators read formatted input in term of "**space separated items**", so

```
aaaaa      bbbb 123
```

are actually three distinct elements. The first two can be string, the third can be a string or whatever numeric scalar type.

If you want to consider spaces as part of the read, the proper function shold be [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)